'org.springframework.util.Base64Utils' is deprecated since version 6.0.5 and marked for removal
In Spring Boot 3.2.4 Base64Utils.encodeToString is deprecated. Do you know how I can migrate this code?

Have you read the javadoc? This tells you what to replace it with.

just use java.util.Base64 replace it  , have you ever read the Base64Utils doc ?
and alternative is like following code snippet
import java.util.Base64;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String originalString = "Hello, World!";
        
        // Encoding to Base64
        String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(originalString.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Encoded String: " + encodedString);
        
        // Decoding from Base64
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
        String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
        System.out.println("Decoded String: " + decodedString);
    }
}


